# JavaScript image zoom and pan (drag)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Any recommendations on zooming a large image and panning around? ideally inline on the page.

I've been using PanoJS (aka GSV2), but now more people are using iPhone/iPad/Android type devices, this library is either too slow, or the older versions do not support dragging (the one I'm using at the moment).

http://code.google.com/p/panojs/

http://www.dimin.net/software/panojs/

My current thought is that using the tiled images approach is too much for these little processors (at maximum zoom trying to drag 144 individual images, from a 3000 x 3000px original image, where each tile is 250x250px).

So probably looking more at loading the original image in an  with a set width/height... and either writing my own JS to zoom/drag, or using another library (which I can't seem to find at the moment)... then there is the question of using jQuery (with jQuery UI for draggable support), or just writing the raw JS myself to keep the amount of code down.

Comment: This is a very broad question that actually includes several more questions. What exactly do you want to know? What means _inline on the page_?

Comment: @WrongAboutMostThings Thanks for looking and commenting, and sorry for the delay (didn't get an email notification)... anyway, I was using those two libraries and neither worked properly on a mobile device, so was asking if anyone had any better alternatives. I ended up having to write my own though which didn't include any libraries (trying jQuery UI for the draggable functionality worked, but there was still a noticeable lag on some of the larger images).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

More so answering my own question, as the standard libraries don't seem to work as well as I needed, I ended up creating my own solution:

https://github.com/craigfrancis/zoomify

The intention is that you can copy this code and then customise it to your own particular requirements... so ideally you should be able to read/understand the code, rather than just dropping it into your project and hoping for the best.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making a viewport for mobile devices of screen width.

set all the images that are outside the viewport for more than one tile to display:none.
Then when the user pans just update the display property.

That way the browser will mainly compute a large element moving with a few images, and then compute the on and off state of some images.

a lot less graphics intensive than to recalculate a graphics heavy div element.

Comment: Thanks @Michael, I did try hacking some of the code for those libraries (more so the older GSV2, which was already in use on the website)... and I couldn't reduce the load when trying to pan those individual images, even with hacks like using a display:none... I ended up creating my own very basic JS which scaled down the 1 image (setting the width/height so the browser did the down scaling), then adding some simple mouseup/down, touch, and key events to allow the scrolling, and changing of zoom level... will be adding to GitHub later.

Answer (score 0):

After looking around for this too, I decided to use [OpenSeadragon](https://openseadragon.github.io/) ([New BSD](https://openseadragon.github.io/license/) licence), an open-source, web-based viewer for high-resolution zoomable images (desktop and mobile). I needed it for the Image Pyramid sources with [Multi-Image](https://openseadragon.github.io/examples/multi-image/) support and [filtering](https://github.com/usnistgov/OpenSeadragonFiltering) capabilities (via one of a multitude of plugins)

Another strong contender was [OpenLayers](https://openlayers.org/) ([2-Clause BSD](https://tldrlegal.com/license/bsd-2-clause-license-(freebsd))). Here's a simple example with [a static image](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/static-image.html), and here's the [complete list of examples](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/).